# SQL set attending to yes if userid = x and eventid = x

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm **very** new to SQL and have been running simple queries from an android app to phpmyadmin using PHP. Now I am having trouble with a slightly more complex query and am even unsure if I have the correct syntax.

I would like to:

1. Check that the user has an entry for an event, if so then update attendance accordingly (In this example, I would update to Yes)
2. If there is no entry for event I would like to insert one(See code)

[image: Visual]

```
SELECT * FROM user_has_event
IF user_user_id = 1 AND event_event_id = 1
  THEN 
    SET attendance= 'Yes'
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO user_has_event (user_user_id = 1, event_event_id = 1, attendance = 'Yes')
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into user_has_event(user_user_id, event_event_id, attendance)
    values (1, 1, 'yes')
    on duplicate key update attendance = 'yes';
```

Note that for this to work, you need a unique index on `user_has_event(user_user_id, event_event_id)` (a primary key with these two columns works just as well).